# Apache Beam Python SDK -Apache Flink Runner Translation Issue

Tags: python-3.x, apache-flink, apache-beam

My objective is to run apache beam python sdk with a flink execution engine using flink runner.
I am using latest flink cluster supported by beam(2.24) i.e. 1.10  and runner1.10.
source is kafka topic.
Looks like the translator of runner is trying to run a docker command inside container and it does not find it. Is this behavior normal?
Below is the code and error that we get:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.external.kafka import ReadFromKafka, WriteToKafka

class Hl7ToFhirTransform(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,element):
        #print("element:",element)
        yield element

def main():



    options = PipelineOptions(["--runner=FlinkRunner","--flink_version=1.10","--flink_master=x.x.x.x:8081","--streaming"])

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        dataFromKafka = p | ReadFromKafka(consumer_config={"bootstrap.servers":'x.x.x.x:19092'},topics=['testData'])
        dataFromKafka | beam.ParDo(Hl7ToFhirTransform())
    


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Error

```
2020-10-01 20:01:00
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:186)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:180)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:380)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4966)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:447)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:432)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:299)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultExecutableStageContext.getStageBundleFactory(DefaultExecutableStageContext.java:38)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory$WrappedContext.getStageBundleFactory(ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.ExecutableStageDoFnOperator.open(ExecutableStageDoFnOperator.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeStateAndOpen(StreamTask.java:990)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$0(StreamTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:448)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:708)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.DockerCommand.runShortCommand(DockerCommand.java:186)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.DockerCommand.runShortCommand(DockerCommand.java:168)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.DockerCommand.runImage(DockerCommand.java:92)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.DockerEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(DockerEnvironmentFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:248)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:227)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Yes, please read https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/environments/

Comment: @ArvidHeise thanks for prompt response .So this essentially means docker should be installed where remote execution environment is running. here it is a remote flink cluster. i included docker installation as part of docker compose file for flink. Now the error i am getting is: "RuntimeError:Received exit code 125 for command 'docker run -d --network=host --env=DOCKER_MAC_CONTAINER=null apache/beam_python3.6_sdk:2.24.0 --id=1-1 --provision_endpoint=localhost:43738'. stderr: docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

Comment: Now i am working to fix docker daemon issue.

Comment: Make sure that Beam can execute docker. You should be able to log into the image and do some simple docker commands. If not, please enable docker-in-docker. Btw I haven't run Beam inside docker myself yet, so I can't help you much further. I ran only PyFlink directly in docker.

Comment: yes got it. So i would like to understand pyflink support for Windowed operation. it states pyflink is dependent on apache beam1.19 where as latest version for beam 1.24. Also in terms of kubernetes deployment for apache flink where the support was added in 1.10. I would like to understand the notable differences in terms of production environment between flink 1.10 and 1.11 and stability of PyFlink. Any links would be appreciated.

Comment: Windowed operations are [supported](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/api/python/pyflink.table.html#module-pyflink.table.window) without Beam. There was a [large article on PyFlink](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/the-flink-ecosystem-a-quick-start-to-pyflink_596150) by the core maintainers. The [release notes](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/07/06/release-1.11.0.html#pyflink-support-for-pandas-udfs) are the best to check differences between 1.10 and 1.11

Comment: @ArvidHeise i was able to run after resolving this common networking issue that happens between python runner and task manager https://www.mail-archive.com/user@beam.apache.org/msg04827.html . Thankyou so much! Appreciate all the help.